# Custom Programming Language ~ How to interact with the Operating System

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to create my own programming language but I am already thinking ahead a little.
Of course when I can compile a little program I won't have a Standart Library at that time,
and you'd have to create one yourself. Now take for example I'd like to add some functionality to print a string to the screen, I am pretty sure I'd have to do a few System Calls to the operating system to get this displayed.

So to the point: What would be the best way to interact with the Operating System?

Possibilities I came up with myself:
- Generate Object Files and link those to the (for example) C Standart Library
- Writing the files with embedded assembly language containing System Calls

I have a feeling there are better possibilities!

I hope you can help me,

Christian

EDIT: It's a compiled language I am creating!

Comment: Is your programming language compiled to native code or does it run in an interpreter or a managed environment of some kind?

Comment: @Joni It's compiled! I will add it to the question!

Comment: Compiled native or you can compile to bytecodes for a VM e.g. Java Runtime.  - The trade off is speed / features / flexibility.

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes Thanks a lot! I am focussing first on compiling to native code! But who knows someday I can ad Bytecode too! You helped me a lot thanks. ( I wish I could give you more credit though.. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two options, like you say yourself. You can link your standard library with the standard C library, so that the I/O functions in your standard library can use C functions. Alternatively you can make system calls to the operating system directly.

The second approach seems like it's going to be more work: The system calls will be different on each operating system, so you'll have to put a lot of work into porting your system. The system calls may not be well documented, causing many frustrations.

You could start by linking your standard library to the C standard library and worry about other aspects of your language for the moment. Later you can look into replacing the C functions you use with syscalls.

Comment: Thanks Joni! This was what I was searching for.:P I will accept your answer! Also as a last follow-up question: Do you know if most programming language's implement their standart library directly with System Calls or in general use the C library? I mean I could imagine that calling System Calls directly might be more efficient. ( Even though you're right when you say it might be really hard and time consuming! )

Comment: I believe most link with the C library: Java, Perl, Python, Haskell (GHC)... Pascal may be an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Stdin and stdout are pretty much the minimum - if you are using a Unix environment you can then gain access to they keyboard, command line and also pipe text in and out to files.

If you are writing a new language - then StdError may also be worth considering too!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? I'd like to write some interface which can contain specific implementations for each OS. But how would I best connect my code to either a library or directly to the OS?

Comment: It depends how much time you want to spend writing the OS specific integrations - if you go the Unix route there are libraries that can be used to emulate the OS features on non unix environments e.g. http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Mmm I don't mind spending a lot of time on it! I'd like it to be stable and good to use if an operating system would change. So the interfaces/classes I create for users to use should be as portable as possible. EDIT: Also! I use windows a lot so I would like to start there!

Comment: Alternatively - leverage the Java JVM - it is cross platform and provides access to hardware and graphics too.  I have compiled and run Java, PHP and Scala on it.