# How to use system call by LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

For study, I want to implement a C-like compiler using LLVM. This compiler can get input, process and output the result.

I know how to use AST to generate LLVM IR to process. But I meet a problem and have no idea about: How to implement output and input function by LLVM IR?

For truly C compiler, most are in stdio.h.

From K&R, I know how to use system call to implement them, But it also needs syscall.h.

I search on Google and someone said using assembly code. It is a method, but I want to know is there any method by LLVM? If not, how to write stdio code by LLVM IR or assembly for linker?

PS. Anyone know the development process of truly compiler, like GCC or Clang? How they write the standard library?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method for this in LLVM. Compilers provide this by themselves, rather like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353978). In general, you'll end up with either a tiny C library that exports the syscalls, or else you'll have some tiny assembler functions with mangled names that match your compiler's mangling and calling conventions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think I need write tiny library after reading Unix source code.